# Scaling down a dynamic body in scenekit

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm setting up a car in scenekit, and I'm trying to scale it down. unfortunately, whenever I add physics to the wheels, they don't scale down anymore.

This is my code:

```
    let chassisNode = getNode("rccarBody", fromDaePath: "rc_car.dae")
    let wheelnode0 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_FL", recursively: true)
    let wheelnode1 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_FR", recursively: true)
    let wheelnode2 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_RL", recursively: true)
    let wheelnode3 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelLocator_RR", recursively: true)

    chassisNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 10, 30)
    chassisNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, Float(M_PI))
    let body = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
    chassisNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.1,0.1,0.1)
    wheelnode1?.scale = SCNVector3(0.1,0.1,0.1)
    wheelnode0?.scale = SCNVector3(0.1,0.1,0.1)
    wheelnode2?.scale = SCNVector3(0.1,0.1,0.1)
    wheelnode3?.scale = SCNVector3(0.1,0.1,0.1)
    body.mass = 80
    chassisNode.physicsBody = body
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(chassisNode)
    // add wheels


    let wheel0 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode0!)
    let wheel1 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode1!)
    let wheel2 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode2!)
    let wheel3 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode3!)

    // set physics
    vehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: chassisNode.physicsBody!,
                                wheels: [wheel0, wheel1, wheel2, wheel3])
    chassisNode.position = SCNVector3(0,-8,0)
    sceneView.scene.physicsWorld.addBehavior(vehicle)
```

The chassis becomes smaller but the wheels remain the same. is there anyway to also scale the wheels while adding physics to them?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Cause I have the same.

Comment: It looks like you can't scale a dynamic body, so I just made the wheels from cylinders and changed their sizes accordingly

Comment: @slimboy isn't the chassis a dynamic body too? i run into this issue too.